# Is it possible to only match wildcard in python regular expression?

Tags: python, python-re

It is the scenario:

Frontend pass the regular expression to backend, then backend get it and execute the regular expression. But i want to just execute the wildcard match.

For example:
Frontend pass `bash-1.*.0`, it works well

But `bash-1.(hello):*.0`, it will not match `bash-1.(hello):1.0`

So is it possible only match wildcard by python re module?

Comment: `*` in a regular expression does not mean a wildcard.

Comment: Add a period before the asterisk and your second example will match

Comment: No it wont @gregory There is no escaping of `()` meaning there is a defined capturing group. Simply adding `.*` will not find a match.

Comment: @PacketLoss there's no mention of a capturing group: the  pattern is `bash-1.(hello):*.0` and the literal string is `bash-1.(hello):1.0`.

Comment: @gregory That pattern does not match. `()` is not escaped, nor is `.`. Both in `regex101` and `re` it does not match. https://regex101.com/r/PQDFky/1

Comment: @gregory To match `bash-1.(hello):1.0` you need to escape the `()` correctly. `bash-1\.\(hello\):.\.0` matches OP's string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoulde use the [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) module in the stdlib if you want glob-style matching. For example:

```
import fnmatch
print(fnmatch.fnmatch("bash-1.(hello):1.0","bash-1.(hello):*.0")) # True
print(fnmatch.fnmatch("bash-1.(goodbye):1.0","bash-1.(hello):*.0")) # False
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `.*` `.` is a wildcard, and `*` is any number (while the comparable `?` is zero or one and `+` is at *least one*)

Answer (score 0):

In `regex` a `.` will match anything except line terminators once, where `.*` will match unlimited times.

In your current pattern, you are trying to match a `.` however are forgetting to escape it, meaning it will match anything. You should correctly escape the `.` and `()` then you will be able to find a match.

```
string = 'bash-1.(hello):1.0'
pattern = 'bash-1\.\(hello\):.\.0'
re.match(pattern, string)
#<re.Match object; span=(0, 18), match='bash-1.(hello):1.0'>
```

https://regex101.com/r/Wj3V7e/1